# Are pull chains available for wall switches?

Tags: electrical

I have a regular wall switch for a ceiling lamp. After floor renovation it became so high that we can not reach it. The idea is to install a pull chain switch so chain will hang on the reachable level. The problem I was not able to find it. Is it available? I can see only fan or lamp switches.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What became so high you cannot reach?

Comment: Ripped out a floor and the switch is now halfway up the wall?

Answer (score 1):

There are ceiling pull-chain switches sometimes used in the UK for bathroom lights, for historical reasons. I don't know how available they would be in the US.

Since you're just switching a lamp, you could get a metal blank switchplate, drill a hole in it, and install a lamp- or fan-type pull-chain switch in the wall box.